# Can I get a free Ubuntu CD?

Tags: live-cd

Can any one help me get a free Ubuntu installion disk in Bangladesh?

Comment: You can ask anyone to download and burn it and send it to you (I'm in India, so i cant send it to you).

Comment: dear kartik,please make me a way to get Ubuntu Cd coz my net speed to poor to download it. i m in  <mashiur1rah@gmail.com> or sms +8801715866617.

Comment: which kind of internet do you have?

Comment: Gsm 2g wireless internet speed up to 20-22kpb/s.but main problem after 30 or 40 minute net connection disconnected.

Comment: @masiur Use torents. In that connection will be disconnected but download will not stop. You will be able to download afterwards. I also had similar problem but I was able to download through torrents.

Answer (score 0):

No, Canonical has stopped shipping free CDs since April 2011. You might want to refer to the above link in the comment as to why they stopped shipping free CDs.